# Display wpf window on second monitor using Prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, multiple-monitors

I am developing a wpf application using Prism that:

opens the application on monitor 1. Should launch a full screen window on monitor 2.

This window will be used to draw graphics.

How do I create 2 windows using Prism? Should I show this using a dialog or is there a better way a window on second monitor and draw grpahics?

Comment: Why is this related to Prism? You create windows by `Window.Show` in wpf, Prism cannot change that.

Comment: I want to  create the window using MVVM. In prism we have CreateShell that creates the main window. Where do I create the new window?

Comment: Wherever you like, just have it created by a factory and call `Show`. Care to explain what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Haukinger   I have to show MainWindow on screen 1 and SecondWindow on screen 2.  For now I have resolved it by creating SecondWindow in MainWindow's constructor after InitializeComponent.   In MainWindow.xaml.cs:
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new SecondWindow().Show();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You have to use System.Windows.Forms to use "Screen" which will provide you connected screens/monitors with resolution, Primary Display and other info.

You have to create another Window/Shell for secondary display along with a separate region manager to manage secondary display's region and navigation.. Refer below method for creation of secondary window and region manager

```
InitializeShell(Window shell) method
```

Now You also have to create a separate Region Manager and store the instance in some global kind of variable to manage navigation on secondary display.

```
protected override void InitializeShell(Window shell)
   base.InitializeShell(shell);
   Current.MainWindow.Show();

   var regionManager = this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
   var secondRegionManager = regionManager.CreateRegionManager();

   SecondaryWindow secondaryWindow = new SecondaryWindow(secondRegionManager);

   System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea;
   secondaryWindow.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
   secondaryWindow.WindowStartupLocation = 
   System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
   secondaryWindow.Top = rectangle.Top;
   secondaryWindow.Left = rectangle.Left;

   secondaryWindow.Show();
   secondaryWindow.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
            
   GlobalVariables.SecondaryRegionManager = secondRegionManager;  // storing in global variable
```